# Video won't show on UIView Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

So I'm building an app that has a view that will play a video when the segue is activated. When you run the simulator, you can hear the audio but not the image. Below is the code that I am using:

```swift
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

class CongratsVideoController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var videoView: UIView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

        setupView()
    }

    private func setupView() {
        let path = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Congrats Screen Apuntalo", ofType: "mov")!)
        let player = AVPlayer(url: path)
        let newLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        newLayer.frame = self.videoView.frame
        self.videoView.layer.addSublayer(newLayer)
        newLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resize
        player.play()
    }


//End of class
}
```

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: viewDidLoad is too early.

Comment: The bounds of the `AVPlayerLayer` may also need to be updated to meet the requirements of it's parent view

Comment: matt what do u mean its to early?

Comment: @crapio99 I think he means that you should call `setupView()` at a later point in time, maybe in `viewWillAppear()` or `viewDidAppear()`.

Comment: I tried placing it where you mentioned, but it is not working still. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Anybody has any other suggestions?